# How to return Future List from DataSnapshot

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to return a Future List from Firebase Database snapshot and this is my code but I cant get it work properly:

```
Future<List<CocheDetailItem>> getCoches(ids) async {
  List<CocheDetailItem> coches = [];
  final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('17082019');
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var id = ids[i];
    dbRef.child(id).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.value != null) {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> jsres = snapshot.value;
        CocheDetailItem coche = CocheDetailItem.fromJson(jsres);
        coches.add(coche);
      }
    });
    print('here is i ${ids[i]} ');
  }
  return coches;
```

}

The return I get is empty Area. Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, `dbRef.child(id).once();` is a async function, so you must wait it ends to get your data. Use `await` keyword to do it.

```
Future<List<CocheDetailItem>> getCoches(ids) async {
      List<CocheDetailItem> coches = [];
      final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('17082019');
      for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var id = ids[i];
        var dataSnapshot = await dbRef.child(id).once();
          if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
            Map<dynamic, dynamic> jsres = dataSnapshot.value;
            CocheDetailItem coche = CocheDetailItem.fromJson(jsres);
            coches.add(coche);
          }
        print('here is i ${ids[i]} ');
      }
      return coches;
    }
```

Comment: Thx, can you edit your answer to include some example if possible with FutureBuilder, please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience to use FutureBuilder

Comment: Ok, tnx anyway, I’ll give it a try when I’m home and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

well.. I don't use firebase but I send a request to my database with this (you have to use async and await)

```
  Future<List<PlaceModel>> getPlaces(String ciudad, String tipo) async {
    Uri request = Uri.http('domain.com', '/getPlaces/$ciudad/$tipo');
    ResponseModel response = ResponseModel.fromJsonMap(json.decode((await http.get(request)).body));
    List<PlaceModel> items = [];
    if(response.res) {
      if(response.value != null) {
        for(var item in response.value) {
          final place = PlaceModel.fromJsonMap(item);
          items.add(place);
        }
      }
    }
    print("Places Loaded: ${items.length}");
    return items;
  }
```

I use my ResponseModel to convert the json answer in an object.
Then I show it with the future builder:

```
class PlacesListPage extends StatelessWidget{
  final _selectedLocation, _selectedList;
  PlacesListPage(this._selectedLocation, this._selectedList);

  final _provider = PlaceProvider();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _provider.getPlaces(_selectedLocation, _selectedList), // async request to database
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) { // check when your request is done
                if(snapshot.data.length != 0) { // check if any data has been downloaded
                  return ListView.builder( // build a listview of any widget with snapshot data
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      // i just return containers but you can use any custom widget, it's like a forEach and use the index var
                      return Container( 
                        child: Text(snapshot.data[index]),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  // If you don't have anything in your response shows a message
                  return Text('No data');
                }
              } else {
                // shows a charge indicator while the request is made
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: I finally decided to accept Augusto's answer because it fits better to my app logic, but your one is good too.